# Error using WAMP with LDAP

Tags: php, ldap

I'm using WAMP and trying to run something like the following:

```
<?php

$ldap = ldap_connect("ldap.example.com");

$user = "exampleUser";
$pass = "examplePass";

if($bind = ldap_bind($ldap, $user, $pass)) {
  // logged in
} else {
  // error message
}

?>
```

Before doing this though, I tried running phpinfo() to see if ldap was installed, and it doesn't appear anywhere.

I've tried the following:

1. Uncommented the following line in php.ini: extension=php_ldap.dll
2. Copied these files into the same directory as php.ini: ssleay32.dll
   and libeay32.dll
3. Added the following to my environment variables: C:\wamp\bin\php
4. Restarted after doing any of these.

I don't really know what I'm doing, but these were the suggestions I found online. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try the answer on this question: http://serverfault.com/questions/240268/setup-ldap-in-wamp

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. 1) mod_ldap.so exists, and 2) uncommented LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so in httpd.conf. When I do the uncomment, it causes WAMP not to start back up.

Comment: I have installed a [wampserver](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) 2 weeks ago and I had to use the php5-ldap library, just ticked the ldap library in PHP extensions and it worked.

Answer (score 6):

This answer may be useful for others who come across this question as it's over a year since the OP posted this question.

I'm running

- WAMP Version: 2.4
- Apache Version: 2.4.4
- PHP Version: 5.4.16

I tried most suggested solutions that a Google search will bring you to and nothing seemed to work. A forum recommended looking at the [PHP pages](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ldap.installation.php)

A user by the name of Frank in the above link recommended to copy `libsasl.dll` to `[apache folder]\bin` despite this only being recommended for earlier versions of php, this file is in the php folder.

```
copy "C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16\libsasl.dll" "C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.4\bin\libsasl.dll"
```

This is what worked for me and LDAP is now showing up when I use `phpinfo()`, although I haven't properly tested it yet besides running the `ldap_connect()` function, but I'm assuming that means it is working and I should be able to use it in my application.

Besides adding `libsasl.dll` to the Apache bin I added `C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\bin` and `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16` to my `PATH` (i.e. the Windows environment variables -> system variables -> path) and I added `ssleay32.dll` and `libeay32.dll` to the both the Apache and php bin, not sure if required but it's working now.

Comment: I'm running same version of Wamp. Copying [php_folder]\libsasl.dll to [apache_folder]\bin\ works fine for me.

Comment: If you have 2 or more PHP version in WampServer, you have to add libsasl.dll into $phpDllToCopy array in c:\wamp\scripts\config.inc.php so that this file will be copied when you switch between PHP versions.

Comment: Works for me with Apache 2.4.9 and PHP 5.5.12

Answer (score 0):

What errors do you get? function does not exist?

Also you should add the following lines after your ldap_connect function:

```
ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 7);

if(!$ldap){
    echo "LDAP Failed To Connect: ".ldap_error($ldap);
}
```

The options set ldap to protocol version 3, which is needed for active directory and alike on server 2k3 and alike and enabled debugging on the ldap connection.

**Update**

Also, run phpinfo() and look for the extensions directory. Navigate to that directory and make sure that php_ldap.dll exists in there.

Comment: I get Fatal error: Call to undefined function ldap_connect() in C:\wamp\www\example.php on line 3. If I add the code you gave me after the ldap_connect() function, it doesn't get passed it. If I add it before, I get Fatal error: Call to undefined function ldap_set_option() in C:\wamp\www\example.php on line 3. I checked the extensions directory and php_ldap.dll does exist.

Comment: Try the following at before your connect statement `dl('php_ldap.dll');`

Comment: That gives Fatal error: Call to undefined function dl() in C:\wamp\www\example.php on line 3

Comment: Looks like dl() is deprecated as of PHP 5.3

Comment: If you run your script from the CLI? `> php -f script.php` what is the output? Does LDAP then get loaded? It is a different SAPI that what apache uses, so worth a test.

Comment: I get a few different warnings: PHP Warning:  dl(): Dynamically loaded extensions aren't enabled in C:\wamp\bin\
php\php5.3.10\example.php on line 3 and PHP Warning:  ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server i
n C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.10\example.php on line 9

Comment: Ok, Great! You are able to talk LDAP now! Remove the dl file. Restart the Apache process again completely. Do not do a reload but a restart. Look for the apache service, stop and start it. If that doesnt work, shut down the machine and restart. The old .ini settings are cached by apache/php.

Comment: I restarted the computer, and removed the dl() function. Still getting the same error - Call to undefined function ldap_connect().

Comment: Another thing to try is, copy, not move, the eay32.dll files to C:\windows\system32. What is your extension_dir line from .ini

Comment: Yeah I should have written copied - I copied the libeay32.dll to that location. My extension_dir in php.ini is commented out as ; extension_dir = "./" and in phpinfo() it's c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.10/ext/

Comment: @bdev .. don't forget to mark the answer as `Answered` to make sure StackOverflow stays organized if the issue was resolved.

Comment: Hey I appreciate the help, but the issue still wasn't resolved.

Comment: Where di we leave off? Is the machine you installed php on a server 2kx machine?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the same problem by adding the `php` folder in the following Windows system path:

at command prompt

```
SET PATH=C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13;%PATH%
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply copied 'libsasl.dll' from the php directory to the apache directory and obviously restarted httpd. This solved my problem.

This was not a WAMP installation, I installed apache and php separately. Perhaps in case of WAMP or LAMP some more files can be needed.

Answer (score 0):

it's very too late, but i had the problem and i wanted to add that you must **uncomment extension=php_ldap.dll**  in **both php and apache's php.ini**.